# How to register HttpContext and HttpContextBase classes using Autofac in ASP.NET application?

Tags: dependency-injection, autofac

I have a SessionWebAppService class that uses HttpContext and HttpContextBase classes in constructors:

```
public class SessionWebAppService : WebAppServiceBase, ISessionWebAppService
{
    public SessionWebAppService(HttpContext httpContext)
        : this(new ConcertDb(), new WebFormContext(httpContext))
    {
    }

    public SessionWebAppService(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        : this(new ConcertDb(), new MvcContext(httpContext))
    {
    }

    public SessionWebAppService(IConcertDb concertDb, IConcertHttpContext httpContext)
        : base(concertDb, httpContext)
    {
    }
```

I should register HttpContext and HttpContextBase classes in ASP.NET application in Global.asax.cs file using Autofac, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using MVC, you can register the `Autofac.Integration.Mvc.AutofacWebTypesModule` to get the web abstractions (e.g., `HttpContextBase`) registered.

If you're not using MVC, you can [look at the source for AutofacWebTypesModule](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/blob/master/Core/Source/Autofac.Integration.Mvc/AutofacWebTypesModule.cs) to see how it's done.